# Node.js - run jasmine continuously with a debugger

Tags: node.js, jasmine, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code on Windows 10, with `jasmine` and `nodemon`

How does one set up their `package.json` such that you can run jasmine continuously, yet also be able to drop breakpoints in visual studio code to debug?  I feel like I've been searching for ages on how to do some kind of setup like this.

Here is what I currently have in `package.json`.  Running this allows me to write in my .spec files and jasmine gets continualy run on each change:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\nodemon --inspect --ext js --exec \".\\node_modules\\.bin\\jasmine\""
},
```

Anyone have a magical command to allow debugging any spec file, or any file which the tests execute against?

Comment: I think you need to set up a `launch.json` to debug your jasmine tests with vscode.